# detecting same variable in a method Java JDT parser

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I've been implementing a Java parser with JDT and i have a problem with detect same variable declaration in same method. For example, i have class such as below:

```
public double method(double[] data) {
    int _ii = 0;
    int _ii = 0; //same variable name, data type and value

    for (int _ii = 0; _ii < _dimensi; _ii++) {
        _temp += data[_ii];
    }
    _output = _temp / _dimensi;

    return _output;
}
```

Above class has two variable with the same name (int _ii = 0), then my goal is find duplicate variable in same method and remove one of them. So that the code will be:

```
public double method(double[] data) {
    int_ii = 0;

    for (int _ii = 0; _ii < _dimensi; _ii++) {
        _temp += data[_ii];
    }
    _output = _temp / _dimensi;

    return _output;
}
```

My code so far:

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

     String str = "public class Classname{"
            + "public double method(double[] data) {\n" +
            "    int _ii = 0;\n" +
            "    int _ii = 0; //same variable name, data type and value\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    for (int _ii = 0; _ii < _dimensi; _ii++) {\n" +
            "        _temp += data[_ii];\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "    _output = _temp / _dimensi;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    return _output;\n" +
            "}"
            + "}";

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());

    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration method){
                            Block block = method.getBody();

                            block.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

                                    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment var) {
                                        System.out.println("Variable " + var.getName()+", in Method "+method.getName()+ "' Method line " + cu.getLineNumber(method.getStartPosition()));
                                        Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

                                        multimap.put(1, var.getName()); // variable name
                                        multimap.put(1, cu.getLineNumber(method.getStartPosition())); // method line
                                        multimap.put(1, method.getName()); // method name

                                        //Then what should i do if found variable name, method line and method name more than one in the Multimap?

                                        return false;
                                    }
                            });


                      return false;
                    }

    });
}
```

Anyone please help me, thanks :)

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you looked at the JDT [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)?

Comment: @greg-449, i have updated my question with code that i have written so far. Please review :)

Comment: You're configuring the parser to expect a compilation unit, that is a Java source file with a class header, but you're trying to parse a method implementation, so it's safe to say it is failing. Try printing cu.getMessages()

Comment: @delephin, yeah i know it. i have edited the sources :) help please